# Add tasks to Project for the web using Power Automate

Tags: ms-project, power-automate, common-data-service

I'm wanting to create a project and add tasks to that project using Power Automate. Using the Common Data Service connector, I can create the project successfully but not the tasks. When I run the flow, I get a "Resource not found for the segment" error for the Project ID. It is the correct ID. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to create a new project, you can use Microsoft Project's "Creates new project" or you can use SharePoint's "Send an HTTP Request to SharePoint"

[image: Step 1.1]

[image: Step 1.2]

There are a two ways to create a new task in Microsoft Project Online (PWA). You can use Microsoft Project's "Create new task" or SharePoint's "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint."

You have to checkout the project and then check it back in. (Please note that the refresh time isn't instant. [See here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/535bb481-7a37-4341-bdd8-971343a3b8ac/project-online-projects-getting-regularly-stuck-in-queue-waiting-to-be-processed?forum=projectonline))

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

PWA is part of Microsoft Project Server 2013.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Project for the web" and "Project Online" are two different things. Is that right?

Comment: Project Web App (PWA) is part of Project Online. Please see the following link (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-started-with-project-web-app-0c5b05b3-b444-438c-8b22-100d87ade40b) and look at the updated photo on the bottom of my answer.